# Adjusting overscan with onboard graphics?

Tags: display, integrated-graphics, amd-catalyst, overscan

I have just purchased a new monitor (AOC I2267F) and I am having issue with black borders around the edges of the monitor.

I get this issue when using both HDMI and VGA (monitor has no DVI port), however the issue is less with VGA, but still exists.

From my own research I believe that I need to adjust the overscan settings inside the AMD Catalyst Control Centre.

The problem is that I have no GPU so the overscan options do not show up in this.

My CPU is the AMD Phenom II X4 965, and the integrated graphics appears to be "ATI Radeon 3000 Graphics (Gigabyte)".

Is it possible for me to adjust the overscan without a GPU, if so, how?

Comment: Do you have the resolution set to 1920x1080 (i.e. the native resolution of the monitor)? Also, see page 18 of the [manual - PDF](http://us.aoc.com/support/documents/pdf/documents/664) regarding the Auto button, which should adjust the display for you.

Comment: A small image with borders is an underscan condition, not overscan.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, the resolution is set to 1920x1080. I have just re-tried the auto adjust feature as described but this made no difference to the black borders around the edges unfortunately.

Comment: @user404 Are the black borders on all four edges? If you read on in the manual to page 22, it shows how to adjust the horizontal and vertical position of the image. It is just possible that if you get the top-left corner correct, the rest of the image will snap into place. And I would use the HDMI connection. If that still doesn't give satisfactory results, you could try alternatives to Catalyst Control Center - I don't have an AMD GPU so I can't suggest anything other than what you might find through Google.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using a laptop to drive the monitor?

I have a dim and distant memory of a similar problem with a laptop driving an external monitor which was resolved by cycling through the laptop video output modes (local display, projector display - local blank, projector display local copy, etc).  In my case Shift F5 or Shift F8 cycled through the modes.  The problem was resolved through experimentation with the video output modes in conjunction with the Windows dual display options.